# Testing html5 file upload with Capybara/Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, selenium, capybara, integration-testing

I'm writing an application which uses html5 file upload capabilities, that is to say a user can drag&drop a file from his desktop in a div an it will be uploaded with [jquery.filedrop](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop).

Anyone knows if it's possible to test it with capybara/selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I am testing this with Selenium WebDriver.
it looks like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source"));
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

[more about Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)

Comment: That looks like dragging and element to another, not dragging a file into an element, or what am I missing? what is source?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I miss part about desktop.
I don't think, that selenium can't manipulate with "out of browser" objects. Never met it before, no docs mention, no information after google scanning.